# Different base for different platform in Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am developing mobile apps for Android and iOS platforms on Phonegap framework. I am using some functions which have different behavior in Android and iOS. So for this shall i maintain 2 different set of codes or is there some other alternative for this.

Which framework is more preferable for such task. I am currently using Sencha touch.

Answer (score 0):

The `device` plugin and `if`/`switch` statements are your friend.

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Then (after receiving `deviceready`):

```
var currentPlatform = "unknown";
if (typeof device !== "undefined") {
  currentPlatform = device.platform.toLowerCase();
}
switch (currentPlatform) {
    case "android":
      // do android stuff
      break;
    case "ios":
      // do iOS stuff
      break;
    .
    . // repeat for platforms you need //
    .
    default:
      // default is technically optional here, but might be useful if you have some
      // fallback that could work on other platforms. Good for throwing an error
      // if running on an unsupported platform for some odd reason or for supporting
      // mobile + desktop during development (could have mock data here or mock
      // operations, etc.)
}
```